# What is the JavaScript .src extension for?

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I just download jqGrid from NuGet and it copied two files

> jquery.jqGrid.min.js
>
> jquery.jqGrid.src.js

I know that `.min` file is the JavaScript in a minified version but I don't understand what the `.src` is for. Looking at the file it looks like a normal JavaScript file. Looking on google I am inundated with results talking about the `src` attribute in linking to files not the actual extension. Can anyone tell me what the point of the `.src` extension? On a side note, how do I get it to work with MVC5's bundling?

Comment: `.src` is simply the non-minified version I think

Comment: Look at the files. Full Code Vs Compressed code.

Comment: It's not an extension just as `.jqGrid` is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`jquery.jqGrid.min.js`, and `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` have the same file extension, which is `.js`. The rest is the file name. `.min` is commonly added to indicate that the file is minified, but it doesn't force the contents of the file to be minified. `.src` is just an indicator that it contains the source of the minified files.

*Why* the author would choose to name the file `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` instead of `jquery.jqGrid.js` is a question for the plugin author, and cannot be reasonably answered here.

Comment: That makes sense, src is short for source. Thanks.

Comment: @Eagle_f90 the **src** files are often included so that when debugging issues, you can reference the .src version instead of the .min version. This means you don't have to step through the minified code and you can learn what the author is doing in their code.

Answer (score 0):

src in the file name indicates that it is the un-minified, un-obfuscated js file. Consider only the last part of the file for extension and rest as qualifiers indicating whether it is minified (min) or not, extensions/plugins to a library etc. Ex:

> jquery.url.min.js - plugin to jquery adding additional functionalties
>   related to handling url and is minified javascript file.